# jQuery Flot Charts: Remove Labels Below Bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, flot

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLsdae1j/)

I need to remove the labels below the bars, thus removing the gap (blank space) between the chart and end of container. The labels are dynamic, so the blank space can bigger or smaller in height.

`display:none` on the `.xAxis .tickLabel` doesn't seem to fix this. This issue appears after updating to last version of the [jquery flot library](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md).

Current and wrong:

[image]

Desired and correct:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want tick labels on your x axis and no vertical grid lines, you can set the `ticks` property to an empty array:

```
    xaxis: {
        tickColor: "FFFFFF",
        ticks: []
    },
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLsdae1j/2/).

If you want to keep the vertical grid lines, you can use an array with empty strings for the tick labels:

```
    xaxis: {
        tickColor: "FFFFFF",
        ticks: [
            [1, ""],
            [2, ""],
            [3, ""],
            [4, ""],
            [5, ""]
        ]
    }
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLsdae1j/3/).

If you need the labels for other functionality in your chart, save the array in a variable and use it from there.

Comment: this might work. any way of keeping the grid vertical lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/L0r76411/3/

Add this to your CSS

```
#example-section15 {
  height: 230px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because the labels are dynamic in length and the blank space can bigger or smaller in height.

Comment: But you have fixed `height` on `flotcontainer` and `canvas` anyways, so i figured this will work.

Comment: Also i don't see any labels.

Comment: comment out the `display:none` and you will see the labels

Comment: How about when you want labels to show you remove this code, when you don't want labels you use `height: 230px`. I am not sure what write height on canvas and other elements.